# "-webkit-app-region: drag" is only works on a portion of the titlebar

Tags: css, electron, tailwind-css

I'm building a custom titlebar for my electron app and I'm trying to make it draggable using `-webkit-app-region: drag`.

I am able to only drag a portion of the titlebar. Everything on the left (green arrow) is draggable and everything on the right (red arrow) is not. Is there any way to fix this?

[image]

Here's the code for my titlebar (I'm using `tailwindcss`):

```
<div className="flex justify-between items-center h-8 p-0 fixed top-0 left-0 w-screen max-w-screen bg-gray-100 :user-select-none :app-region-drag">
  <div className="flex items-center gap-2 h-full w-full pl-2">
    <img src={favicon} className="w-5 h-5" alt="app-logo" />
    <h1>App Name</h1>
  </div>
  <div className="flex items-center h-full">
    {maximized ? (
      <ContractButton onClick={handleMaximizeToggle} />
    ) : (
      <MaximizeButton onClick={handleMaximizeToggle} />
    )}
    <MinimizeButton onClick={app.minimize} />
    <CloseButton onClick={app.quit} />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't figure out why it doesn't work with `tailwindcss`, but adding this has the intended functionality I'm looking for.

**App.css**

```
/* Click titlebar to drag app window */
body section#titlebar {
  -webkit-app-region: drag;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

body section#titlebar button {
  -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
}
```

New titlebar

```
<div id="titlebar" className="flex justify-between items-center h-8 p-0 fixed top-0 left-0 w-screen max-w-screen bg-gray-100">
  <div className="flex items-center gap-2 h-full w-full pl-2">
    <img src={favicon} className="w-5 h-5" alt="app-logo" />
    <h1>App Name</h1>
  </div>
  <div className="flex items-center h-full">
    {maximized ? (
      <ContractButton onClick={handleMaximizeToggle} />
    ) : (
      <MaximizeButton onClick={handleMaximizeToggle} />
    )}
    <MinimizeButton onClick={app.minimize} />
    <CloseButton onClick={app.quit} />
  </div>
</div>
```